# B-tree indexing example

Tags: postgresql, database-internals, btree

I am trying to understand "how" Postgres creates the indexes using b-trees with an example.

To be specific, I am looking to understand how the b-tree will look like when the ("Name") & ("Username" and "SSN"- **Composite index**) respective indexes are created on the below table (doesn't matter but lets assume there are 1 million records):

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsYBh.png]

If "Name" index is created, what will the B-tree look like? Is it something like:

[image]

In the above diagram for b tree 3,1,4,2 are the row ids. So does the b tree store the key, value and the row id in the node?

I read [How does Postgres make its B-tree index?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/111603) but it didn't answer my question.

Comment: https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/anatomy

Comment: Please tell us on what columns exactly the index is defined, and what are the definitions of these columns.